# How to quickly show/hide a vertical line in current cursor in VIM?

Tags: vim

I have this in .vimrc

```
set colorcolumn=80                                                              
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27
```

So there's constantly a vertical line in vim.

Sometimes I need to quickly show and hide another vertical line to see if some text is aligned or not in current cursor.

How can I do that?

If I first find out the column number of current cursor and use `:set colorcolumn=48`, the vertical line will move to column 48, then I have to use `:set colorcolumn=80` again to move it back.

Just wonder if there's other neat way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set cc=80
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=235 guibg=#2c2d27
nno <silent> <key> :<c-u>let &l:cc = &l:cc =~# ',' ? 80 : '80,'.strchars(matchstr(getline('.'), '.*\%'.col('.').'c.'), 1)<cr>
```

In the mapping, replace `<key>` with the key sequence you want to use:

```
nno <silent> <key> :<c-u>let &l:cc = &l:cc =~# ',' ? 80 : '80,'.strchars(matchstr(getline('.'), '.*\%'.col('.').'c.'), 1)<cr>
             ^^^^^
```

When you press your key sequence, Vim should highlight a second column at your current position.
When you press it again, Vim should stop highlighting this second column.

Comment: It would be nicer to use longforms (colorcolumn and nnoremap)